# Address Parsing PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex

I got struct with to parse the Door number/Flat number from address. So kindly guide me how to do this using regex. Also i have tried with following regex to parse that but it doesn't works what we expected.

```
preg_match('![0-9/-]+!', $address, $matches);
```

Also i have added few sample inputs and expected output

```
Input
#302 MEENA RESIDENCY NEW ALLAPUR 600032
Expected Output
302

Input
No 35/2 2nd main 2nd cross subramanium l ayout viginapura ramurthy nagar 600032
Expected Output
35/2

Input
17-13-54 jonnaguddi vzm,near bhashyam school 600032
Expected Output
17-13-54

Input
Floor 4,plot no 285 2 birla mansion d d sathe marg prathana samaj girgaon mumbai 600032
Expected Output
285

Input
3-a  birla mansion d d sathe marg prathana samaj girgaon mumbai 600032
Expected Output
3-a

Input
3a birla mansion d d sathe marg prathana samaj girgaon mumbai 600032
Expected Output
3a

Input
3/a birla mansion d d sathe marg prathana samaj girgaon mumbai 600032
Expected Output
3/a

Input
3/2a birla mansion d d sathe marg prathana samaj girgaon mumbai 600032
Expected Output
3/2a

Input
3a/2 birla mansion d d sathe marg prathana samaj girgaon mumbai 600032
Expected Output
3a/2

Input
3/2-a birla mansion d d sathe marg prathana samaj girgaon mumbai 600032
Expected Output
3/2-a

Input
3-a/2 birla mansion d d sathe marg prathana samaj girgaon mumbai 600032
Expected Output
3-a/2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
~(?:#|\bno\s*|^)(\d+(?:[/-]?\w+)*)~im
```

or

```
~(?:#|\bno\s*|^)\K\d+(?:[/-]?\w+)*~im
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Muw0XN/1)

**Details**:

- `(?:#|\bno\s*|^)` - either of:

  - `#` - a hash sign
  - `\bno\s*` - a whole word followed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `^` - start of a line
- `\K` - a match reset operator  discarding the text matched so far in the current iteration
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:[\/-]?\w+)*` - 0+ sequences of:

  - `[\/-]?` - an optional `/` or `-`
  - `\w+` - 1+ letters/digits/`_`

Comment: Note that if you process separate strings, the `m` modifier is not needed (that means you may replace `~im` with `~i`).

Answer (score 0):

#### Expression

This regex selects the desired numbers in group 1:

```
/^(?:#|.*?\bno\s+)?(\d[\w\-\/]*)/gmi
```

It performs the same selection as Wiktor Stribizew's one, but in less steps.

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/IFENHf/1)

#### Explanation

- `^` asserts the start of a line
- `(?:#|.*?\bno\s+)?` indicates the number is **possibly** preceded by:

  - a `#` character
  - a word `no` followed by at least one space
- `(\d[\w\-\/]*)` captures the number that start with a number and can be composed of a letter, a number, a dash `-` or a slash `/`.

> If you test your string one at a time, the `m` flag (multiline) isn't necessary.